# type error: object has no method of split

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I have been doing an exercise on codewars, however my code passes the tests but it gives a typeError. Couldn't figure out why. Be great if I could get some help... Thanks!

The task is to create a function that can take any string and randomly jumble the letters within each word while leaving the first and last letters of the word in place.

Here's my code:

```
function shuffle(a) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length; i; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        x = a[i - 1];
        a[i - 1] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
};

mixwords = function(string){

  var array = string.split(" ");

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var itemArray = array[i].split("");
    if (itemArray.length > 2) {
      var first = itemArray.shift();
      var last = itemArray.pop();

      shuffle(itemArray);
      itemArray.unshift(first);
      itemArray.push(last);
      var newItem = itemArray.join("");
      array[i] = newItem;
    }
  };
  console.log(array.join(" "));
  return array.join(" ");
};
```

The error message goes like this:

> TypeError: Object 23 has no method 'split' at mixwords
>
> /runner/frameworks/javascript/cw-2.js:273
>
> throw ex;
>                             ^

Comment: How are we supposed to know? I don't even see you calling anything.

Comment: you're assuming something is of type `String`, which has a `.split` method, but instead that something is of type `Number`.  Which is line 23?

Comment: PHPglue, sorry, the reason I didn't call the function at last was because the code was supposed to pass some test. Just for you: mixwords("winter is coming");

Comment: Thanks Dan O, I think you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You essentially need to sanitize whatever gets passed into the function as the `string` parameter, in case it's of the `Number` type.

```
mixwords = function(string){
  string = typeof string !== 'string' ? string.toString() : string;
  var array = string.split(" ");

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var itemArray = array[i].split("");
    if (itemArray.length > 2) {
      var first = itemArray.shift();
      var last = itemArray.pop();

      shuffle(itemArray);
      itemArray.unshift(first);
      itemArray.push(last);
      var newItem = itemArray.join("");
      array[i] = newItem;
    }
  };
  console.log(array.join(" "));
  return array.join(" ");
};
```

Alternatively, if you need to simply return immediately if a parameter is not a `string`, this would be the solution:

```
mixwords = function(string){
  if ( typeof string !== 'string' ) return; // just 'return' to return 'undefined'

  var array = string.split(" ");

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var itemArray = array[i].split("");
    if (itemArray.length > 2) {
      var first = itemArray.shift();
      var last = itemArray.pop();

      shuffle(itemArray);
      itemArray.unshift(first);
      itemArray.push(last);
      var newItem = itemArray.join("");
      array[i] = newItem;
    }
  };
  console.log(array.join(" "));
  return array.join(" ");
};
```

Comment: Thanks amdouglas, very helpful however, it failed one test and the error message is: ✘ Expected: undefined, instead got: '23'. Here are some of the tests: Test.assertEquals(mixwords(23),undefined);
Test.assertEquals(mixwords(true),undefined); It looks like I need to return undefined if variable string is not a string?

Comment: So, instead of converting to a string, you need to check if string is of type `string` and if not, return. Like this: `if ( typeof string !== 'string' ){ return; }`

Comment: Awesome! Passed all tests no errors. Thank you!

Comment: Not a problem, glad to help.